# Fixing missing data- how to transform table into ts object that works with KalmanRun?

Tags: r, datetime, kalman-filter

I'm working with data from SteamCharts on a game- Warframe (https://steamdb.info/app/230410/graphs/)

Edit- The data is a .csv downloadable near "Steam charts for every day"

I'm modelling this timeseries data, but the package I'm using requires no missing values. To resolve this, I'm using arima to predict the missing values (instructions from link reproduced below)

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104565/how-to-use-auto-arima-to-impute-missing-values

```
require(forecast)
# sample series
x0 <- x <- log(AirPassengers)
y <- x
# set some missing values
x[c(10,60:71,100,130)] <- NA
# fit model
fit <- auto.arima(x)
# Kalman filter
kr <- KalmanRun(x, fit$model)
# impute missing values Z %*% alpha at each missing observation
id.na <- which(is.na(x))
for (i in id.na)
  y[i] <- fit$model$Z %*% kr$states[i,]
# alternative to the explicit loop above
sapply(id.na, FUN = function(x, Z, alpha) Z %*% alpha[x,], 
  Z = fit$model$Z, alpha = kr$states)
```

As of now, I've managed to convert to

1. Convert the Date strings to a DateTime object in my dataframe:

```
df <- read.csv(file="chart.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
df = df %>% select(DateTime, Players)
df_temp[['DateTime']] <- as.Date(strptime(df[['DateTime']], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

2. Get an xts object of my data (I believe arima only works with ts though)

```
df = xts(df$Players, df$DateTime)
df = ts(df)
```

The arima model fits, but when I try to use the KalmanRun, I get the following error:

```
Error in KalmanRun(x, fit$model) : invalid argument type
```

I believe there's an issue in how I'm converting it to a timeseries object, but don't know how to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!